# Write huge rows in Excel file (.xls format older version) in chunks without loading complete file in memory

Tags: java, apache-poi, aspose-cells, spire.xls

I'm working on a feature to export data into Excel file (**.xls** (Older version) format support).

I have to append chunks into **.xls** file, **without loading file into memory.** The file should be in .xls format. chunks size can very in each steps and there are millions of rows . divided in chunks.
If I load file in memory, there can be a situation of **memory-overflow.** Can someone can suggest any free or paid api or solution in java which can help.

Comment: https://github.com/dhatim/fastexcel is an alternative to POI SXSSF

Answer (score 1):

#### Update - User wants to append, my suggestion is not able to read workbooks. Leaving it here for any reference.

Use a `SXSSFWorkbook` which is part of the Streaming API of POI. It makes it possible to keep only a specific limit of rows in memory while writing. It is a lot faster than using a normal Workbook.

This is for the newer format though. You should know that using the old `.xls` format, you are more limited on row and column count. Check [this](https://docs.aspose.com/cells/net/find-maximum-rows-and-columns-supported-by-xls-and-xlsx-formats/#:%7E:text=For%20example%2C%20XLS%20supports%2065536,1048576%20rows%20and%2016384%20columns.) for more.

```java
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(10); // 10 is the row access window. It keeps only the last 10 rows in memory, then they are removed and the next ten are loaded
```

For more take a look at [this](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html), in the **SXSSF (Streaming Usermodel API)** part.

P.S: Do not forget to `workbook.dispose()`.